# How to Upgrade Angular2 Version using Angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 Project using Angular 2.0.x version. Can I upgrade to the latest version 2.3.x using some Angular cli command. Or do I need to do it manually by changing the package.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upgrade command is not yet implemented in angular-cli. Though, it is an open issue on github and is scheduled for RC1.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/314

For now it seems, we have to make do with updating package.json